# Triggers in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to do a trigger that updates a sum of all credits on update of the grade or a insert of a new one. That's my tables

```
create table Department (
             Department_ID varchar(4) not null,
             Name varchar(25) unique,
             Department_Head_ID varchar(9),
             College_ID varchar(4),
             Credits_To_Degree NUMBER(3),
             constraint pkDepartment primary key (Department_ID));

create table Enrollment (
            Student_ID varchar(9) not null,
            Course_ID varchar(5) not null,
            Registered_Date date,Grade NUMBER,
            Status varchar(4),constraint pkEnrollment primary key 
            (Student_ID, Course_ID)); 

create table Student (
            Student_ID varchar(9) not null, 
            First_Name varchar(25),
            Last_Name varchar(25), 
            Phone char(11), 
            Birth_Date date, 
            Street varchar(100), 
            Zip_Code char(5),
            Department varchar(4),
            Credits integer,
            Eligible char(4), constraint pkStudent primary key
            (Student_ID),constraint fkDeptId foreign key (Department)
            references  Department(Department_ID));

           ALTER TABLE Department ADD FOREIGN KEY (Department_Head_ID)  
           REFERENCES  Faculty(Faculty_Id) INITIALLY DEFERRED;
           ALTER TABLE Department ADD FOREIGN KEY(College_ID) REFERENCES   
           College(College_ID) INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

the trigger:

```
   create or replace TRIGGER Credits
   after INSERT OR UPDATE 
   ON enrollment
   REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   UPDATE STUDENT 
   SET CREDITS=(SELECT SUM(c.CREDITS) FROM COURSE c,ENROLLMENT e 
   WHERE c.COURSE_ID = e.COURSE_ID 
   and e.STUDENT_ID = :new.student_id
   and e.GRADE>= 60 ) 
   WHERE STUDENT.STUDENT_ID=:new.student_id;
   END;
```

The trigger compiles but when i change value of the grade a get this error

```
UPDATE "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT" SET GRADE = '60' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAGUSAABAAALKJAAF' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3540016'
ORA-20003: An error has occurred while performing credits trigger
ORA-06512: at "FELIX.CREDITS", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FELIX.CREDITS'


One error saving changes to table "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT":
Row 6: ORA-20003: An error has occurred while performing credits trigger
ORA-06512: at "FELIX.CREDITS", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FELIX.CREDITS'
```

line 5 is a FOR EACH ROW command
I figure out that the problem is in the :new.student_id. But how could i get the id of the row that the triggers fires upon.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Change all your :new references to :old.  see the change in my answer

Comment: i tried that already. same error.

Comment: try this, changed your joins

Comment: Your error handling is terrible. You are replacing a detailed error message with a generic one. All this accomplishes is making it harder to determine what went wrong. Unless you intend to add logging to the trigger, you'd be best served by removing it altogether.

Comment: 2 kevinsky Same error, the joins are ok i tried this with a definitive id and it worked. The problem is in getting the student_id right.

Comment: 2  Allan How i can add a more detailed error message? I am using sql Developer

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT(SQLERRM);  gets you started, you should log the message in a production system

Comment: To start with: take the current handling out. Let the error that Oracle provides propagate.

If you need to add error logging at some point, it should look something like `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS /*Your error logging procedure goes here*/ RAISE; END;`.

Never replace a meaningful error with a meaningless one.

Comment: when i commented the exeption handling i get that error. One error saving changes to table "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT":
Row 6: ORA-04091: table FELIX.ENROLLMENT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "FELIX.CREDITS", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FELIX.CREDITS' the problem that i am doing a select query on the table that i am changing after STUDENT

Comment: You definitely don't want to refer to `old` since this trigger works on `INSERT` (where there won't be an `old` to reference) as well as `UPDATE`. So `new` is correct there. Two, normally this sort of trigger should be an `AFTER` trigger. Use `BEFORE` triggers to update values in the *same* table, `AFTER` triggers to update values in *other* tables.

Comment: i change the trigger so he is not using the student table and i still getting the mutating error

Comment: i finally did the trigger with assumtion that the data correct and i need only to add a number of credits if the grade is >60 on the insert trigger and add another trigger on update that if the grade is changed from fail to pass add the credit and if from pass to fail substract. Thanks for all your help